# How do I Make this jQuery Animation function work from Bottom-to-Top?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, margins

I've tried editing the JS for the animation function in Zoomer.js, here's the code:

```
$('.title').animate({marginLeft:'2px',marginTop:'65px'},d.speedTitle).css({'z-index':'10','position':'absolute','float':'none'})}}},function(){$(this).css({'z-index':'0'});
$(this).find('img').removeClass("hover").stop().animate({marginTop:'0',marginLeft:'0',top:'0',left:'0',width:'100px',height:'100px',padding:'0px'},d.speedRemove);$(this).find('.title').remove()})}}})(jQuery);
```

I'd like for the little red box to animate from the bottom up rather than from the top to bottom. I thought it would be as simple as changing marginTop:'65px' to marginBottom:'35px' but that's not doing the trick.

I've read that using position:absolute renders marginBottom ineffective, but if I use any other position it breaks the effect. If this is correct, is there a work-around? If this is not correct can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

I appreciate everyone's time and input.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try animating the `bottom` property?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - was messing with a fiddle, and that works. You should post as an answer :) http://jsfiddle.net/JTyVV/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your element is absolutely positioned, you can animate its [bottom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/bottom) property:

```
$(".title").animate({
    marginLeft: "2px",
    bottom: "35px"
}, d.speedTitle);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I can see it works fine in Fiddle, but when I plug it into the site it's just not working right.  I think it is because I have this zoom plugin working alongside jCarousel and some wires are crossing. (you can see it [here](http://www.remotereplacer.com))

Comment: A possible explanation would be that one or both of the two plugins are setting the `top` CSS property on your element, which would conflict with our use of `bottom`.

Comment: I've poked around & can't find the culprit - but thank you for your help at any rate...

Odd thing is it now animates from bottom-to-top in IE, but top-to-bottom in FF lol